# How to integrate Admob Native Ads in Android Groupie recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, native-ads, groupie

I am looking for any example to add Native Ads in Groupie.

My code for adding items in recyclerview is:

```
recycler_view_user.apply { layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@UserFragment.context) adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>().apply { userSection = Section(items) add(userSection) setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create another Groupie Item with Native Ads implementation and add it to your adapter. First of all, try to create Ads from [Native Template](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates). Afterwards, you can create your own Native Ads Template if you need it.